# data-lazy beautifulsoup html find

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am having problems calling specific attributes in beautifulsoup

```
<div class="route_list "
data-id="11234" 
data-lazy="ubt" 
data-ubt-company="ABC" 
data-ubt-departuredate="2016-11-10" 
data-ubt-destcountry="China," 
data-ubt-from="Shanghai" 
data-ubt-mark="Bus" 
data-ubt-price="2399" 
data-ubt-sailingid="11185" 
data-ubt-score="4.4" 
data-ubt-sourcefrom="Cruise" 
data-ubt-voyaid="1184">
```

I am trying to extract only the company and departure date and the following code returns a key error.

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser") 
div=bsObj.div
departure = div.attrs['data-ubt-departuredate']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be targeting the desired `div`, *narrow down your search*:

```
div = bsObj.find("div", class_="route_list")
```

Or, checking the presence of the `data-ubt-departuredate` attribute:

```
div = bsObj.find("div", {"data-ubt-departuredate": True})
```